Use of environment variable or appsettings as a counter, good or bad practice
I'm wondering if it's bad practice to have a variable in a webserver which counts the amount of incoming requests and put it in an environment variable.
In C# for example you have System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings which is originally filled with values from you appsettings.
I'm thinking of using it to store a (somewhat global) variable there. An other option would be to just create a public static Globals where I could put the counter in but I do not like that kind of files (though the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is practically the same).
Am i missing a good alternative?
Would it be bad practice to use something like ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to hold a counter? (I see the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings as a store for environment variables).
EDIT:
The variable is being used to add to response headers and will be used in the frontend.

are you really asking if a global variable is a good idea? No, its not

Generally speaking, env variables are terrible,  but sometimes necessary. In your case they are just terrible. May I ask why you don't use a reverse proxy for your website? Reverse proxies usually track the number of requests, either by default or enabled through some config.

I am not familiar with reverse proxy, sounds like it's more overhead than i would need though.

If you want to store and make accessible the number of requests hitting your website, log it as a metric and query your metrics in a report.
You can do this out of the box with most logging solutions, or write your own performance counter.
If you want to use the number of requests say to implement some real time throttling, again use a metric, but make it accessible via dependency injection so that other services can query the in memory value.
Writing to app settings has always been a bit dodgy and should be avoided.

Environment variables are terrible: they're for passing hidden parameters into new processes, and should be avoided otherwise.
You could put it in settings, but it's not a setting?
What do you want to do with this number?

just create a public static Globals where i could put the counter in but i do not like that kind of files

It's reasonable not to like globals. What's the replacement for globals in C# web apps? DI services.
It sounds a little silly to define a CounterService that's just one variable, but I think that's the most idiomatic way to do this.

"It sounds a little silly to define a CounterService that's just one variable, but I think that's the most idiomatic way to do this."
Yes I was afraid of that.

Is what the OP asking about a bad design? Yes, for the same reason that mutating global state is bad. As for an alternative design? No idea. We need to know how this counter is being used. Mutating shared global state might actually be what is needed, but then again counting incoming requests could be more about metrics and performance. In that case, the OP needs a specialized tool for this, not a global variable.

On the other hand, "number of incoming requests" is truly global state. It is mutable, but it isn't going to change unexpectedly (quite the opposite, frequent changes are absolutely expected). So apart from having to write threadsafe or even process safe code to increase it, and the fact that whatever you read might not be the latest state anymore a seond, a microsecond or a nanosecond later, it is fine to use as a global variable

Not a good idea due contention
A global request counter would be subject to multithreading concerns. Each thread handling a request would need to put a file lock on the configuration file, read the old value, write the new value, and release the file lock. Only one thread could do this at a time-- the others would have to wait-- which means you've just turned your lovely scaleable web application into a single-threaded lumbering brick.
Counting requests is a common problem and there are much more standard solutions out there. The simplest is to enable W3C logging (for example in this answer), suck the records into an aggregator (such as splunk), and run a query on it to count records.
